# Integrating $x/(x-2)$ from $0$ to $5$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How would one go about integrating the following?

$$\int_0^5 \frac{x}{x-2} dx$$

It seems like you need to use long division, split it up into two integrals, and the use limits. I'm not quite sure about the limits part.

Comment: It will turn out that the integral does not exist. That may be clearer if you drag the bad point to $0$, by letting $x-2=u$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integrand $\frac{x}{x-2}$ has a vertical asymptote at $x=2$. Therefore
the integral 
$$
\begin{equation*}
I=\int_{0}^{5}\frac{x}{x-2}dx=\int_{0}^{2}\frac{x}{x-2}dx+\int_{2}^{5}\frac{x
}{x-2}dx=I_{1}+I_{2}
\end{equation*}
$$
is an improper integral of the second kind. It exists only if both integrals 
$I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ exist. Let's compute the first one using the
substitution $u=x-2,dx=du$, as commented above
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
I_{1} &=&\int_{0}^{2}\frac{x}{x-2}dx=\int_{-2}^{0}\frac{u+2}{u}
du=\int_{-2}^{0}1du+\int_{-2}^{0}\frac{2}{u}du \\
&=&2+2\int_{-2}^{0}\frac{1}{u}du=2+2\ln \left\vert u\right\vert
_{-2}^{0}=2+2\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}\ln \left\vert u\right\vert
_{-2}^{-\varepsilon },\quad \varepsilon >0 \\
&=&2+2\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}\ln \left\vert -\varepsilon
\right\vert -2\ln \left\vert -2\right\vert  \\
&=&2-2\ln 2+2\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}\ln \varepsilon .
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Since $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}\ln  \varepsilon
 $ ($\varepsilon>0$) doesn't exist, the integral $\int_{-2}^{0}\frac{2}{u}du$ does
not converge and so does $I_{1}$. Similarly we might conclude that $I_{2}$
does not converge as well.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, exactly, you do want to use "long division"...

Note, dividing the numerator by the denominator gives you:

$$\int_0^5 {x\over{x-2}} \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^5 \left(1 + \frac 2{x-2}\right) \mathrm{d}x$$

Now simply split the integral into the sum of two integrals:

$$\int_0^5 \left(1 + \frac 2{x-2}\right) \mathrm{d}x \quad= \quad\int_0^5 \,\mathrm{d}x \;\; + \;\; 2\int_0^5 \frac 1{x-2} \,\mathrm{d}x$$

The problem, of course, is what happens with the limits of integration in the second integral: If $u = x-2$ then the limits of integration become $\big|_{-2}^3$, and we will see that the integral does not converge - there is a discontinuity at $u = 0$, and indeed, a vertical asymptote at $x = -2$, hence the limit of the integral - evaluated as $u \to 0$ does not exist, so the integral does not converge. And so the sum of the integrals will not converge.

Answer (score 3):

Shashwat, the antiderivative of $1/x$ is not $\ln(x)$, but $\ln|x|$.
So in the computation there wouldn't be any natural log of $-2$.
The reason that this integral does not exist, is as stated earlier, the discontinuity issues at $x=2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \int$$\displaystyle {\frac{{dx}}{{ax + b}}}$ = $\displaystyle {\frac{{1}}{{a}}}$$\displaystyle \int$$\displaystyle {\frac{{dt}}{{t}}}$ = $\displaystyle {\frac{{1}}{{a}}}$ $\ln| t| + C =$ $\displaystyle {\frac{{1}}{{a}}}\ln| ax + b| + C$.

where

$ax + b = t$

Comment: You might also want to add a note about what happens with those limits of integration.

Comment: And the $x$ on the numerator.